# Recall update of custom binding manually from the "outside", somewhere in the ViewModel?

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

Is there a way, to manually update a custom binding with a new Array ?

**MARK-UP:**

`<div data-bind="myCustombinding: dataBindArray...">`

**TypeScript**

```
public dataBindArray: KnockoutObservableArray<sometype>;
...
this.dataBindArray = ko.observableArray([]);
```

**Is there something like this ?**

`ko.getTheRightBinding("myCustombinding")(dataBindArray).update()`

Comment: I need to redraw the contents of the HTML with the new data

Comment: The whole point of knockout is to have the UI automatically respond to changes in your data so there's definitely a way to do what you want, but what exactly are you trying to achieve? Why can't you update the elements in the existing array?

Comment: Just change the data. `this.dataBindArray([...some new data...])`